# Is it possible to use TcpClient and connect directly to a program listening on Azure VM?

Tags: c#, azure, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a simple Client/Server program in C# using TcpClient/TcpListener, and I was wondering if its possible to test it on Windows Azure VM. The TcpListener listens on IPAddress.Any.

I want the server to listen on the VM, and the client connect to it. Its not an Azure application, just regular application.

I created an endpoint with the same public/private port for the VM but that didn't seem to work.  I suspect the problem may have to do with the way the TcpClient is working, resolving the domain of the VM to a IP Address.

Is that possible to do anyway, or are there restrictions about it ? I tried searching but what I found were Azure-specific applications, and not "general" ones that could run without azure-related configurations.

Comment: Since you are using just a VM on azure, I believe that it's totally possible. Did you configure the firewall restrictions correctly?

Comment: If you are using an Azure Vm, you can do it. You need to look the network configurations on Azure, since you need to create a route from the public IP Address, to the VM internal IP Address, and also, open the firewall to allow communication between an internet public IP address/range, to the Azure public IP Address.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was possible. Just make sure to make the endpoint not load balanced (ie: make sure to leave "Create Load Balanced Set" and "Enable Direct Server Return" unchecked).